# Cannot use the same shortcut for compiling Markdown for Jupyter Notebook files and compile Python code for Python files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running Windows 11. I have  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  set to run .py files. When I am editing Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) files,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  still works for compiling the Python cells but does not work for compiling Markdown cells. [Here is what my shortcuts page looks like in VSCode. The compiling .py file shortcut is boxed in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m3on.png)

As soon as I remove  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  for compiling .py files,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  now works for Markdown cells for .ipynb files. Is there a way that I can keep the same keyboard shortcut for both compiling .py files and Markdown cells for .ipynb files? This way I can use the same universal shortcut for compiling code and not have to manually change anything in the shortcut menu.

Comment: please copy and paste from your keybindings.json file instead of a screenshot.

Comment: `// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "python.execInTerminal-icon"
    }
]`